# Derivative problem with two differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

a) Let  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two differentiable everywhere functions such that $f(0)=2$ ,  $f′(0)=3$, $f′(x)=g(x)$ and $g′(x)=−f(x)$. Show that  $f^2(x)+g^2(x)=13$ for all values of $x$.

b) Find a function $h(x)$ such that $h′(−1)=1/2$,  $h′(0)=0$, and  $h′′(x)>0$ for all  $x$, or prove that such a function cannot exist.

Comment: Sven, could you please show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing. I don't know where to start.

Comment: For the first part think about $h(x)=f^2(x)+g^2(x)$ for  second use LMVT

Comment: Yes! Great starting point, I'll try what comes out of MVT.

Comment: @SvenClark let me know when you are stuck

Comment: What is  $h'(x)$ in (a)?

Comment: there is no $h'(x)$ in part a?

Comment: Sorry, Friday night... Differentiate your sum of squares ( I called this h)  and you can simplify and integrate again..

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to solve the first part but I am still having problems with the MVT for the second part. How do I substitute the info given into the MVT theorem?